# Make 3 paired columns from one Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a query that I try to make over a table in database.

So my table has a column with names like this :

[image]

I want a query that will select names and ids in the following mode:

either

[image]

or

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If this is for formatting output, you might be better off performing the simpler query, and constructing the displayed tables manually.

Comment: What's your motivation?  It's hard to imagine a case where this is good practice.

Comment: I want this for a script that makes DataTables.js server processing

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join and calc the id

```
@my_len = 3

select a.id as id, a.name as name, b.id as id1, b.name as name1, c.id as id2, c.name as name2
from my_table as a
inner join my_table as b where a.id = b.id+@my_len
inner join my_table as c where a.id = c.id+@my_len*2
```

Comment: Choose differing output names for columns that are the same. Consider a `cross join` to fold the variable in.